# Steps sync to wrong day when I bucketByTime with TimeUnit.DAYS as 1

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

We have several customers reported this kind issues, for example, a user have 1,361 steps at day 11/17/2021, but 0 steps at 11/18/2021, but the google's app "google fit" shows 149 steps at 11/17 and 1,212 steps at 11/18.

we read log to see a dataPoint as follow:
start=Wed Nov 17 23:34:17 PST 2021, end=Thu Nov 18 19:57:49 PST 2021, name=com.google.step_count.delta, fields=[steps(i)]
It is as long as more than 1 day.

Questions:

1. How is google's app google fit ready steps, Is it using same way as the document here?
   https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total
   Or it use some other ways? Or there is an algorithm update at google fit recently? Because we didn't see this issue before.
2. We tried a solution to bucket by hours and sum the step, this issue gone, but it is not a good solution, it take more time, 24 times data, need more memory. Is there a good solution to avoid this issue?

Code:

```
    val estimatedStepsDelta = DataSource.Builder()
      .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
      .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
      .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
      .build()

    return DataReadRequest.Builder()
      .setTimeRange(startTimeEpochSeconds, endTimeEpochSeconds.coerceAtLeast(startTimeEpochSeconds + 1), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
      .aggregate(estimatedStepsDelta, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_MOVE_MINUTES, DataType.AGGREGATE_MOVE_MINUTES)
      .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
      .enableServerQueries()
      .build()
```

Comment: Google Fit App is using the way found in the documentation. Steps in particular have some extra validation applied to make the final step count as accurate as possible. Google Fit detects when users are doing activities that shouldn't contribute to their step count (like cycling, driving or travelling via public transport) and removes these from the final step count. 
The Google Fit app shows this more accurate, estimated step count on both the Android and iOS app, and the Google Fit app on smart watches with Wear OS.